# after puttin php syntax, my website get stuck at preloader

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, session

I have this code on my php file for navbar:

```
<?php if(!$session->is_logged_in()) {
        echo '
        <a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        Login <span class="label"> login to system</span> </a>
      </li>';}
      else
      {
      echo '
       <a href="#!" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                  ' . $session->user_name; . '<span class="badge bg-default">2</span> <span class="caret"></span> <span class="label">it is you</span>
                </a>';
      }
      ?>
```

I check if the session is set using `(!$session->is_logged_in())`

If it is not set I should get a login button on `navbar`.

If the session is set, I should get his username `($session->user_name)`.

On my website I have a preloader (astral-gaming.com) but after inserting this code and uploading this file, every page which had included it, isn't shows.

It's just the preloader and it doesn't go to the page.
After deleting that code, everything is fine.
What I should do?

Comment: remove semicolon after `$session->user_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `;` after`$session->user_name;`

Comment: this ; is doing more problem to me then everything else. Everytime I have a problem with this. Or I forget to put, or I put too much.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the help.